# For an infinite set $A$, does $|A| = |A \times A|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that $|\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{N}^2|$, and that $|\mathbb{R}| = |\mathbb{R}^2|$.  It seems like this might be true for all sets, but I don't know how to go about proving this.

It's easy to prove that $|A| \leq |A \times A|$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347752/proving-that-if-a-is-a-non-empty-set-then-a-a-times-a)).  So to prove the claim it suffices to show that there exists some injective function $f : A \times A \to A$.

For $A = \mathbb{N}$, you can use e.g. $f:p, q \mapsto (p+q)^2 + p$.  For $A = \mathbb{R}$ you can construct various space-filling curves.  But I'm not sure how such constructive solutions can be generalized, if at all.

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: The claim is true in general but certainly not easy to prove. And it relies on some aspect of choice. In general, cardinal arithmetic is well-behaved if you accept choice. You can find a proof of the claim in any (good) text on axiomatic set theory, as well as some good texts on logic and set theory.

Comment: @IttayWeiss This not just relies on some aspect of choice, it is in fact equivalent to choice.

Comment: Thanks @AndresCaicedo. Indeed, what I meant is that for a set of given infinite cardinality a slightly weaker choice principle is needed, but for the general result full choice is required.

Comment: There are many questions on this site addressing this, you may want to spend a few minutes looking for them. In short: This is true, but it is equivalent to the axiom of choice. One way of proving the equality is to use choice to well-order $A$, and then use that for infinite cardinals $\alpha$, we have that $\alpha$ and $\alpha\times\alpha$ are in bijection as shown, for instance, using Gödel's pairing.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!  It seems like Gödel's pairing is a natural way to generalize the usual bijection offered from $\mathbb{N}^2$ to $\mathbb{N}$.  Care to upgrade your comment to an answer?

Comment: @augurar: This shouldn't be answered it should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If you can substantiate that claim with a link, please do so and I will delete the question.

Comment: Here we go: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/608538/622 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/180671/622 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/54892/622 and there might be a few more. Search through the linked and related questions (appearing on the right of the thread) to find those.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks, I have voted to close.  Somehow I didn't see these in my search.  The second link you mention is the closest duplicate.